# How to controll what child element to append depending on submition of form element

Tags: javascript, html

Still new to JS
I'm trying to handle a submission of a form with input elements of type radio in a way that it will trigger appending a new element to "main" element, using the value set by what the user chooses. That's the main functionality I'm looking for with this.

My code consists of 4 main js functions: three that assist creation and appendage of new elements; one that creates p elements (prGenerator), one that creates the input radio (createOption) and one that creates the form (createRadioInput), and one called foo that calls createRadioInput to which a (fifth) function is passed that has a switch used to select what new p element to append next based on input set at the point where submission handling is defined for the form when the submit button is hit.
**The problem is that the switch always defaults to default, regardless of the value passed, and I don't understand why.**

Here's my code, the important bits are the foo function, specially when it calls createRadioInput, and inside createRadioInput when the event listener is defined for the created form:

```html
<body>
  <div id="main">
  </div>
  <script>
    function foo() {
      const options = [];
      const groupName = "group1";

      prGenerator("Choose and option to render the next:");

      options.push(createOption("option1", groupName, 0, "Render option 1"));
      options.push(createOption("option2", groupName, 1, "Render option 2"));

      const lambExec = (input) => {
        console.log("pased input to lambExec: " + input);

        const storyOption1 = "Option 1 selected: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs";
        const storyOption2 = "Option 2 selected: A B C D E F G H I J K L M O P Q R S T U V X Y Z";

        switch (input) {
          case 0: //branches out to check zach story
            prGenerator(storyOption1);
            break;
          case 1: //branches out to return to study room
            prGenerator(storyOption2);
            break;
          default: //switch will always default to this... why?
            prGenerator("...No option given.");
            break;
        }
      };
      createRadioInput("form1", groupName, options, lambExec);
    }

    /**@param formName unique name for the group of input radio elements
     * @param groupName the name of the relevant radio input elements
     * @param options list of option object (see createOptions function) that will be used to append  to the main HTML element
     * @param exec passed lambda to rexecute after sumition
     * @desc given a name and an list of options, it will create and append the input radio elments into the main HTML element**/
    function createRadioInput(formName, groupName, options, exec) {
      let input = -1;
      const main = document.getElementById("main"); //getting parent HTML element to append
      let newForm = document.createElement("form"); //creating form
      newForm.action = "#"; //form's data stays on the page
      newForm.name = formName;

      //this function to execute after form detects subition event
      const handleSubmition = (event) => {
        const group = document.getElementsByName(groupName); //get relevant group of options
        for (let i = 0; i < group.length; ++i) {
          if (group[i].checked) {
            input = group[i].value;
            console.log("submited: " + input);
          }
          group[i].disabled = true;
        }

        console.log("input before passing to exec() inside handleSubmition inside createRadioInput: " + input);
        //FIXME: Why is input not working?
        exec(input); //part of the story to execute after submition

        event.preventDefault(); //to avoid reloading after sumition
      };
      newForm.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmition); //add a new event listener

      options[0].input.checked = "checked"; //FIXME: maybe we don't want this... make the first option the default
      //innerinner function as a lambda to apply to each element in otpions
      const lambForEach = (current) => {
        newForm.appendChild(current.input);
        newForm.appendChild(current.label);
        const br = document.createElement("br");
        newForm.appendChild(br);
      };
      options.forEach(lambForEach); //append option

      //appending the submit element
      const submit = document.createElement("input");
      submit.name = groupName;
      submit.type = "submit";
      submit.value = "Continue";
      newForm.appendChild(submit);

      main.appendChild(newForm);
    }

    /**@param id the ID for the input
     * @param name name for the radio input
     * @param value the value to be returned if slected
     * @param text the inner text for the label of input
     * @desc helper function to create user input of type radio*/
    function createOption(id, name, value, text) {
      //creating the input radio element
      let newInput = document.createElement("input");
      newInput.type = "radio";
      newInput.id = id;
      newInput.name = name;
      newInput.value = value;

      //creating the lable
      let newLabel = document.createElement("label");
      newLabel.for = id;
      newLabel.innerHTML = text;

      return {
        input: newInput,
        label: newLabel
      };
    }

    /**@param str string to display on the website
     * @desc automatizes the creation of pr elements*/
    function prGenerator(str) {
      const main = document.getElementById("main");
      const pr = document.createElement("p");
      pr.innerHTML = str;
      main.appendChild(pr);
    }
  </script>
  <script>
    foo()
  </script>
</body>

<footer>
  this is a footer
</footer>
```

Also, if anybody has any suggestions in how to better achieve the previously described functionality, like maybe using promises and handling them(?).

Comment: `<footer>` has to be a child element of the `<body>` element. Outside of the body-element it will be an invalid Markup! Validate your code yourself by using a [Markup Validator](https://validator.w3.org/). The body has to contain the entire content of a website. Do not mistake it with the main-content that exludes the header and footer which would be sementically the `<main>`-element.

Comment: Form values are **always** strings, your switch case is looking for integers. Use `case("0") .... case("1")` etc.  Either that, or `parseInt` your input.

Answer (score 0):

Just as @Jon P explained in the comment to my question, a form returns String values, and the switch was using ints. So switch should be `case "0":... case "1":`, etc.

Next time, a debugger should be used instead of just printing to the console